# My App crashed at this line in Gaming program in iOS 9.2.1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

[CCAnimation animationWithFrame:frame
                                                                                    frameCount:2
                                                                                         delay:0.5]

```
self.abc    = [CCSequence actions:
                           [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
                           [CCSpawn actions:
                            [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:[CCAnimation animationWithFrame:abc
                                                                                frameCount:2
                                                                                     delay:0.5]
                                      restoreOriginalFrame:YES],
                            [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(abc)],
                            nil],
                           [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.5],
                           [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(abc)],
                           nil
                           ];
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? the entire code for the animation would be helpful and what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I added more code @virgildebique

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are trying to do? I guess abc is some other name? It looks like you have an object abc, you have called your animation abc and you are trying to call a function abc.